# Add Field that has hrs and mins value

Tags: php, mysql, explode, hour, minute

Im trying to display the total for each project group. The Problem is that all the values for that field are recorded like so:

```
0h 06m
```

The sum is displaying as:

```
0
```

with the following code. How do i display the total result in proper HH:MM format

```
<?
$query = "SELECT taskname, SUM(tasktime) FROM tictoc WHERE uid = '6' GROUP BY taskname"; 

$result = mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error());

// Print out result
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
    echo "<br />";
    echo "Total ". $row['taskname']. " = <strong>". $row['SUM(tasktime)']."</strong>";
    echo "<br />";
}
?>
```

Comment: What is the data type of the `tasktime` column? VARCHAR or similar? Can you guarantee it's always in a certain format?

Comment: You should convert those strings to native time values, or at least store them as integers(seconds) so you CAN sum them directly.

Comment: I dont have too much control over how they are recorded, since the values are coming from an excel that employees will upload. The type is varchar and values will be entered by users as 00h 00m

Answer (score 2):

If `tasktime`  is a timestamp data-type, then you can use `DATE_FORMAT(tasktime,'%Hh %im')`.